# recently-used.xbel is empty and entries are never added

Tags: 15.10, gedit, gtk3

I'm on a fairly new install of 15.10 and I noticed in gedit that I have no list of recently opened files.  "~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel" is there and writable but the contents are the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xbel version="1.0"
      xmlns:bookmark="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/desktop-bookmarks"
      xmlns:mime="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info"
></xbel>
```

If I open a file in gedit the timestamp on the file changes so something is being done with the file but the contents never change.

### Edit:

I thought to try running gedit via the terminal to see if there were any error messages.  When I closed gedit I got the following (**though I suspect they have nothing to do with this issue**):

```
** (gedit:5614): CRITICAL **: gedit_multi_notebook_get_active_tab: assertion 'GEDIT_IS_MULTI_NOTEBOOK (mnb)' failed

(gedit:5614): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_action_group_get_action: assertion 'GTK_IS_ACTION_GROUP (action_group)' failed

(gedit:5614): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_action_set_sensitive: assertion 'GTK_IS_ACTION (action)' failed
```

Comment: What are permissions for `recently-used.xbel`? Maybe it isn't writable? `ls -al` tells me mine is `-rw-------`.

Comment: @DKBose - I have the same permissions.  If it was a permission issue it probably wouldn't update the file timestamp.

Comment: What about the contents of `settings.ini` in `~/.config/gtk-3.0` or `/etc/gtk-3.0`? Is there something like `gtk-recent-files-limit=0` in there? But that should affect all gtk3 apps.

Comment: Please check > System Settings > Security & Privacy > Files & Applications > and make sure that `Record file and application usage` is enabled.

Comment: @DKBose - I think this _IS_ affecting all gtk3 apps, I just don't have much installed yet.  GIMP shows no past history too.  I don't have any home directory gtk settings.ini file and there's no files-limit setting in `/etc/gtk-3.0`.  I'm assuming the default isn't 0, right?

Comment: @doug - snap!  I think I shut that off at some point and forgot!  That solved it.  Please post as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I did the same thing on one of my installs, was stumped for a bit. Finally ran `dconf dump  /  > settings.log` & while reading thru saw I'd disabled that option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Gedit and  Nautilus aren't showing any Recent entries & ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel is no longer being written to then most likely from changing the default Privacy settings.

To check open System Settings > Security & Privacy > Files & Applications > and make sure that `Record file and application usage` is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Under Linuxmint Cinnamon, this is under Preferences > Privacy

The default setting for "Remember recently accessed files" is OFF.

I turned that ON, and set "Never forget old files" to ON, also.

I opened GIMP and Inkscape several times, & when I opened recently-used.xbel, I found this: (stripped out most lines)

```
<bookmark href="file:///home/homer/Untitled.xcf" 
<bookmark href="file:///home/homer/Untitled.png"
<bookmark href="file:///home/homer/Desktop/1Pictures/Screenshot%20from%202019-08-10%2018-51-38.xcf" 
<bookmark href="file:///home/homer/puzzles/3_simultaneous_equations/PuppyTortoiseChook.svg"
```

This appears to have fixed it.